# Not allowing a user to ssh within a server with a different account.

Tags: linux, ssh

Imagine a user is logged in as test@example.com .

Now the test user is trying to ssh from the current server to another server using someone else's account. For example :

test@example.com:~$ ssh sombody@example.com

Is there a way to not to allow test to ssh using somebody's account?

I searched online and looked at /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and couldn't find anything useful .

********* Let's say "test" knows the password of "somebody" . But for monitoring and tracking purposes we want every individual to use their own account not somebody's account. So this way when test does test@example.com:~$ ssh sombody@example.com , then when test types the password it says permission denied. even if the password is correct.

Comment: You need to change `somebody`'s password.

Comment: If you could do it, it would be just the first mole in a game of whack-a-mole.  `Test` will just ssh to a shell account elsewhere (there are still free shell accounts), then ssh back in.  Or simply find an offsite TCP/IP proxy.  And this is not considering him logging in there the first time, then making a entry is `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for himself.   Michael Hampton is right. Worry more about the password being out there before worrying about multiple sessions.  Besides, maybe it was `Somebody` using `test`'s password to login, so the second login was not the problematic one.  :)

Comment: Another approach is to introduce dual factor authentication where you tie a user identity not only to what they know (I.e. a username/password combination) but also to a OTP token

Comment: Just like [HBruijn](http://serverfault.com/users/37681/hbruijn) said you can introduce two-factor authentication into the situation. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication) is a tutorial showing you how to set up two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to hate me, but the answer is, "No."

The *problem* is, the destination server has no way of knowing whether you currently control the origin server.  If someone hacks the origin server, or simply breaks security for the "test" user (hack, find password, unsecured terminal, etc.), the destination server would have no way of knowing, making a "block remote user 'x' from connecting as local user 'y'" option pointless.